# Problema com div's que não se "encaixam"

Tags: javascript, html, css, div

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Perdão pela página bugada, vou colocar algumas imagens a seguir de como ela está de verdade:

Essa imagem mostra onde eu coloquei as duas divs, uma ao lado da outra, já tentei várias coisas, usar col-sm, até mudar com margin-left e margin-top, também tentei o z-index pensando que poderia corrigir o problema,  mas o que acontece é que ele fica em cima da sombra... Eu sei que é um problema básico, então perdão...

[image]

```js
  (function() {
            //Show Modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                $('.firstBlur').addClass('modalBlur');
            })
            //Remove modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                $('.firstBlur').removeClass('modalBlur');
            })
        })();


        $('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
            $('.active-link').removeClass('active-link');
            $(this).addClass('active-link');
        });
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('#search');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input');
let active = false;

body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.id === 'search' || e.target.id === 'search-input' || e.target.id === 'search-icon') {
    if(!active) {
      searchBtn.classList.add('active');
      searchInput.classList.add('active');
      active = true;
    }
  } else {
      searchBtn.classList.remove('active');
      searchInput.classList.remove('active');
      searchInput.value = '';
      active = false;
  }
});

       new InitPxVideo({
  videoId: "myvid",
  captionsOnDefault: true,
  seekInterval: 20,
  videoTitle: "PayPal Austin promo",
  debug: true
});
```

```css
 .animate {
        -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
        animation: animatezoom 0.6s
    }


    a {
        outline: none;
    }

    .navbar-container {
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #008080;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #333333;
        
        font-size: 0;
        
        position: relative;
       


    }

    .navbar-container ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: right;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        
    }

    .navbar-container ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        
    }

    .navbar-container ul li a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: color 0.5s;
        
    }

    .navbar-container ul li .underline {
        height: 3px;
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 0%;
        transition: width 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
        margin: 0 auto;
        
    }

    .navbar-container ul li.active-link .underline {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        
    }

    .navbar-container ul li:hover .underline {
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        
    }

    .navbar-container ul li:hover a {}

    .navbar-container ul li:active a {
        transition: none;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
    }

    .navbar-container ul li:active .underline {
        transition: none;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0)
        }

        to {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1)
        }
    }

    @keyframes animatezoom {
        from {
            transform: scale(0)
        }

        to {
            transform: scale(1)
        }
    }

    /* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        span.psw {
            display: block;
            float: none;

        }

        .cancelbtn {
            width: 100%;
        }

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1.5; } 
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0;}
100% { opacity: 1.5; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1.5; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1.5; }
}

.fadeIn {
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
-o-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
}
    


body {
  
  font-family: Caviar Dreams;
margin: 0 auto;
  color: #FFF;
  
}

#search {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: solid 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-left: 530px;
  margin-top: -65px;

}

#search-input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: none;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s;
   margin-left: -35px;
}

#search.active {
  width: 350px;
}

#search-input.active {
  width: 260px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  visibility: visible;
}



 #hero {
       background-color: #e6ffff;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 525px;
         box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        


    }

    #hero2{
        margin-top: -25px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        height: 255px;
       width: 50%;
       float: left;

    }

    #hero3{
        margin-top: -25px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        height: 255px;
       width: 50%;
       float: right;
       box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }





    .row{
        width: 300px;
        margin-top: -500px;
       
    }

    

    .logo2{
        height: 600px;
        width: 600px;
    }

      #wrapper {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

     
   #wrapper {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #brand a,
    p a {
      border: 1px #fff dotted;
    }

    #brand a:focus,
    p a:focus {
      border: 1px #999 dotted;
      outline: none;
    }

    p {
      padding-top: 1em;
    }

    .t2{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.iconc{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.iconi{
    margin-left: 125px;
}




#jum1 { 
 
  background-color: #c2FFFF;
  margin-top:265px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
#jum2 { 
 
  background-color: #c244FF;
  margin-top:0px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  
}

#hero4{
width: 50%;
margin-top: 269px;
}

#hero5{
width: 50%;
margin-top: -168px;
float: right;
background-color: #e9FFFF;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .custom-controls .transcript-link {
    margin-top: -44px;
  }
}
.transcript-single {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black-thirty;
}
.transcript-single.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.session--watch {
  margin-bottom: HalfLineHeight;
}
.session--watch .button {
  background: black-sixty;
  margin-top: QuarterLineHeight;
}
.session--watch .button:hover,
.session--watch .button:active,
.session--watch .button:focus {
  background: black-seventy;
}
.sr-only {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show-inline {
 
}
.px-video-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: 554px;
  margin-top: 0px;



}
.px-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.px-video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;

}
.px-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  


}
.progress-bar {
  width: 85%;
 
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .progress-bar {
    width: 89%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 970px) {
  .progress-bar {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1795px) {
  .progress-bar {
    width: 97.5%;
  }
}
.px-video-controls {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.px-video-controls:after {
  
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.px-video-progress {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.px-video-progress[value] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
}
.px-video-progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #EFFBFB;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.px-video-progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #008080;
 
}
.px-video-time {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}

.px-video-playback-buttons {
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  min-width: 145px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-playback-buttons {
    float: none;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -120px;
    min-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;

  }
}
.px-video-controls button {
  border: 1px transparent solid;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: no-repeat url("../images/px-video-sprite.svg");

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button {
    background-size: 150%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  }
}

.px-video-controls button:focus {
  border: 1px #999 dotted;
  outline: none;
}
.px-video-controls button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart {
  background-position: -9px -331px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:focus {
  background-position: -9px -295px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-restart {
    background-position: -9px -523px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:hover,
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:focus {
    background-position: -9px -466px;
  }
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind {
  background-position: -9px -187px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:focus {
  background-position: -9px -151px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind {
    background-position: -9px -295px;
  }
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:hover,
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:focus {
    background-position: -9px -238px;
  }
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play {
  background-position: -8px -43px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play:focus {
  background-position: -8px -7px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-play {
    background-position: -8px -67px;
  }
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-play:hover,
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-play:focus {
    background-position: -8px -10px;
  }
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause {
  background-position: -9px -115px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:focus {
  background-position: -9px -79px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-pause {
    background-position: -9px -182px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:hover,
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:focus {
    background-position: -9px -124px;
  }
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward {
  background-position: -10px -259px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:focus {
  background-position: -10px -223px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-forward {
    background-position: -10px -409px;
  }
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:hover,
  .px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:focus {
    background-position: -10px -352px;
  }
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container {
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 12px;

}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container label {
 
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  background: no-repeat url("../images/px-video-sprite.svg");
  background-position: -6px -943px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .px-video-fullscreen-btn-container label {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label {
  outline: 1px #999 dotted;
  background-position: -6px -907px;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:hover+label {
  background-position: -6px -907px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label {
  outline: 1px #999 dotted;
  background-position: -6px -907px;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background-position: -6px -979px;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked:hover+label {
  background-position: -6px -1015px;
}
.px-video-captions-btn-container {
  float: left;
}






.px-video-controls input[type='range'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 6px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  outline: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .px-video-controls input[type='range'] {
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 85px;
  }
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  outline: 1px #999 dotted;
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: none;
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  height: 10px;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: #666;
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: #666;
  border: none;
  height: 12px;
  width: 8px;
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  .px-video-controls input[type='range'] {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 8px;
    top: -3px;
  }
  .px-video-controls .px-video-time {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }

}
.px-video-controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.progress-bar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 75%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .progress-bar {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 590px) {
  .progress-bar {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 970px) {
  .progress-bar {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1795px) {
  .progress-bar {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
.px-video-progress {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.px-video-time {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.px-video-playback-buttons {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .px-video-playback-buttons {
    left: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding-left: 96px;

  }
}

}
.px-video-controls button {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<body class="fadeIn">

    <!-- TODA PROGRAMAÇÃO DEVE SER FEITA DENTRO DA DIV firstBlur!!!-->

    <div class="firstBlur">

        <div class="navbar-container">

            <ul>
                <li class="nav-link active-link">
                    <a href="#">Página inicial
                    </a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Vídeos</a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#">Quem somos?</a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" href="#">Entrar</a>
                    <div class="underline">
                        
                    </div>

                </li>

           
            </ul>

                <div id="search">
  <i class="fas fa-search" id="search-icon"></i>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="search-input" name="search" autocomplete="off">
  </form>
</div>
    </div>
   








<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero">
<!-- you can also add something like style="min-height: 70vh;" to the div above -->
    <div class="container">
   
      
 <div class="px-video-container" id="myvid">
      <div class="px-video-img-captions-container">
       
        <div class="px-video-wrapper">
          <video poster="images/Logotipo.jpg" class="px-video" controls>
                <!-- video files -->
                <source src="videoteste.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                

                <!-- text track file -->
                

                <!-- fallback for browsers that don't support the video element -->
                <div>
                    
                        <img src="images/Logotipo.jpg" class="logo2" alt="download video" />
                    
                </div>
            </video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end container for captions and video -->
      <div class="px-video-controls"></div>

    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 class ="ti">Bem vindo ao site do <h2 class=
                "t1" style="color:#008080">Projeto AVAL!</h2></h2>
                <p>
                    <h5 class="t1">Assista esse vídeo que explica nosso projeto:</h5>
                </p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero2">
     <div class="row2">
            <div class="col">
              <strong><h2 class="t2" style="color:black">Funcionalidades do site</h2></strong>>

            
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero3">
     <div class="row2">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="images/iconv.png" class="iconv"/>
                <img src="images/iconc.png" class="iconc"/>
                <img src="images/iconi.png" class="iconi"/>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero4">
    <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
       <div class="row3">      
         <div class="col">             
         </div>           
      </div>
     </div>
    







<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero5">
     <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="row3">      
         <div class="col">             
         </div>           
       </div>
     </div>
    






</div>











      


        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true">

            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color:black">Faça o login!</h5>


                    </div>



                    <div class="modal-body">


                        <!-- Início do formulário -->

                        <form class="log">
                            <div class="imgcontainer">

                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="logotipo.png" alt="Avatar" class="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="container">
                                <label for="uname"><b>Nome</b></label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="uname" required>

                                <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha" name="psw" required>

                                <button type="submit" class="shadow-pop-tr" style="background-color:#008080">Entrar</button>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Lembrar de mim
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="container1" style="background-color:#008080; height: 60px;">

                                <span class="psw" style="margin-top:0px">Esqueceu a<a href="#"> senha?</a></span>
                                </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    


    <!-- Fim do formulário -->







    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/strings.js"></script>
  <script src="js/px-video.js"></script>
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender direito. O que fica em cima da sombra? Pela imagem mostrada, as duas divs estão ao lado da outra, não? Até porque no título da pergunta vc diz uma coisa e no texto outra coisa. Veja: no título vc diz que o problema é que as divs não se encaixam, não ficam uma ao lado da outra. Já no texto vc diz que o problema é com a sombra, e a imagem mostra as duas divs uma ao lado da outra. Tá mt confuso de entender.

Comment: Opa perdão, aquelas duas estão certas... o problema está nas duas divs debaixo que quando são "colocadas" lá não ficam com a sombra (A sombra das duas divs de cima).

Comment: Fiz um correção, adicionei uma foto de como fica, para vc entender o problema, espero que ajude, eu realmente tentei corrigir de várias formas por horas, mas como sou inexperiente é meio complicado para mim =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que vc usou a classe `jumbotron jumbotron-fluid` como se fosse um `container`, e isso não funciona assim.

Troque tudo que for

`<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">`

por

`<div class="container-fluid">` e vai normalizar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
  .animate {
-webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}


a {
outline: none;
}

.navbar-container {
text-align: left;
background-color: #008080;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #333333;

font-size: 0;

position: relative;



}

.navbar-container ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;

}

.navbar-container ul li {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;

}

.navbar-container ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
transition: color 0.5s;

}

.navbar-container ul li .underline {
height: 3px;
background-color: transparent;
width: 0%;
transition: width 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
margin: 0 auto;

}

.navbar-container ul li.active-link .underline {
width: 100%;
background-color: white;

}

.navbar-container ul li:hover .underline {
background-color: white;
width: 100%;

}

.navbar-container ul li:hover a {}

.navbar-container ul li:active a {
transition: none;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
}

.navbar-container ul li:active .underline {
transition: none;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
}

to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
from {
    transform: scale(0)
}

to {
    transform: scale(1)
}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;

}

.cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1.5; } 
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0;}
100% { opacity: 1.5; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1.5; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 1.5; }
}

.fadeIn {
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
-o-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
}



body {

font-family: Caviar Dreams;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #FFF;

}

#search {
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
border: solid 5px;
border-radius: 50px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 35px;
transition: 0.3s;
margin-left: 530px;
margin-top: -65px;

}

#search-input {
height: 100%;
width: 0px;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: 600;
background: none;
color: #FFF;
border: none;
outline: 0;
visibility: hidden;
transition: 0.3s;
margin-left: -35px;
}

#search.active {
width: 350px;
}

#search-input.active {
width: 260px;
margin-left: 16px;
visibility: visible;
}



#hero {
background-color: #e6ffff;
background-size: cover;
height: 525px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);



}

#hero2{
margin-top: -25px;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
height: 255px;
width: 50%;
float: left;

}

#hero3{
margin-top: -25px;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
height: 255px;
width: 50%;
float: right;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}





.row{
width: 300px;
margin-top: -500px;

}



.logo2{
height: 600px;
width: 600px;
}

#wrapper {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


#wrapper {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#brand a,
p a {
border: 1px #fff dotted;
}

#brand a:focus,
p a:focus {
border: 1px #999 dotted;
outline: none;
}

p {
padding-top: 1em;
}

.t2{
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 80px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.iconc{
margin-left: 100px;
}

.iconi{
margin-left: 125px;
}




#jum1 { 

background-color: #c2FFFF;
margin-top:265px;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
}
#jum2 { 

background-color: #c244FF;
margin-top:0px;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;

}

#hero4{
width: 50%;
margin-top: 269px;
}

#hero5{
width: 50%;
margin-top: -168px;
float: right;
background-color: #e9FFFF;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.custom-controls .transcript-link {
margin-top: -44px;
}
}
.transcript-single {
border-bottom: 2px solid black-thirty;
}
.transcript-single.hidden {
display: none;
}
.session--watch {
margin-bottom: HalfLineHeight;
}
.session--watch .button {
background: black-sixty;
margin-top: QuarterLineHeight;
}
.session--watch .button:hover,
.session--watch .button:active,
.session--watch .button:focus {
background: black-seventy;
}
.sr-only {
position: absolute !important;
clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
padding: 0 !important;
border: 0 !important;
height: 1px !important;
width: 1px !important;
overflow: hidden;

}
.hide {
display: none;
}
.show-inline {

}
.px-video-container {
overflow: hidden;
min-width: 300px;
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
margin-left: 554px;
margin-top: 0px;



}
.px-video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}


.px-video-wrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
height: 0;
z-index: 1;

}
.px-video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;



}
.progress-bar {
width: 85%;

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.progress-bar {
width: 89%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 970px) {
.progress-bar {
width: 95%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1795px) {
.progress-bar {
width: 97.5%;
}
}
.px-video-controls {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.px-video-controls:after {

font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
.px-video-progress {
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 10px;
}
.px-video-progress[value] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border: none;
}
.px-video-progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
background-color: #EFFBFB;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.px-video-progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
background-color: #008080;

}
.px-video-time {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
float: right;
line-height: 30px;
margin-top: -30px;
font-size: 14px;

}

.px-video-playback-buttons {
float: left;
line-height: 20px;
min-width: 145px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-playback-buttons {
float: none;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -120px;
min-width: 200px;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;

}
}
.px-video-controls button {
border: 1px transparent solid;
background: transparent;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 5px;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
overflow: hidden;
background: no-repeat url("../images/px-video-sprite.svg");

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button {
background-size: 150%;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
}

.px-video-controls button:focus {
border: 1px #999 dotted;
outline: none;
}
.px-video-controls button {
cursor: pointer;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart {
background-position: -9px -331px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:focus {
background-position: -9px -295px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart {
background-position: -9px -523px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-restart:focus {
background-position: -9px -466px;
}
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind {
background-position: -9px -187px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:focus {
background-position: -9px -151px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind {
background-position: -9px -295px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-rewind:focus {
background-position: -9px -238px;
}
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play {
background-position: -8px -43px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play:focus {
background-position: -8px -7px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play {
background-position: -8px -67px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-play:focus {
background-position: -8px -10px;
}
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause {
background-position: -9px -115px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:focus {
background-position: -9px -79px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause {
background-position: -9px -182px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-pause:focus {
background-position: -9px -124px;
}
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward {
background-position: -10px -259px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:focus {
background-position: -10px -223px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward {
background-position: -10px -409px;
}
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:hover,
.px-video-controls button.px-video-forward:focus {
background-position: -10px -352px;
}
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container {
float: left;
width: 25px;
margin-top: 12px;

}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container label {

width: 25px;
height: 20px;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-left: 1px;
background: no-repeat url("../images/px-video-sprite.svg");
background-position: -6px -943px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container label {
margin-top: 5px;
}
}

.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label {
outline: 1px #999 dotted;
background-position: -6px -907px;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:hover+label {
background-position: -6px -907px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label {
outline: 1px #999 dotted;
background-position: -6px -907px;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
background-position: -6px -979px;
}
.px-video-fullscreen-btn-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked:hover+label {
background-position: -6px -1015px;
}
.px-video-captions-btn-container {
float: left;
}






.px-video-controls input[type='range'] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 6px;
width: 70px;
margin-top: 9px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 5px;
background-color: #e6e6e6;
outline: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
.px-video-controls input[type='range'] {
margin-top: 12px;
width: 85px;
}
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
outline: 1px #999 dotted;
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
-moz-appearance: none;
height: 6px;
background-color: #e6e6e6;
border: none;
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none !important;
height: 10px;
width: 6px;
background-color: #666;
}
.px-video-controls input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
background-color: #666;
border: none;
height: 12px;
width: 8px;
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
.px-video-controls input[type='range'] {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
height: 8px;
top: -3px;
}
.px-video-controls .px-video-time {
margin-top: 4px;
}

}
.px-video-controls {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
}
.progress-bar {
flex-grow: 1;
width: 75%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.progress-bar {
width: 75%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 590px) {
.progress-bar {
width: 85%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 970px) {
.progress-bar {
width: 85%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1795px) {
.progress-bar {
width: 85%;
}
}
.px-video-progress {
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
}
.px-video-time {
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
padding-left: 10px;
margin-top: 0;
}
.px-video-playback-buttons {
flex-grow: 1;
min-width: auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
.px-video-playback-buttons {
left: auto;
margin-left: auto;
min-width: auto;
position: relative;
width: auto;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: no-wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
padding-left: 96px;

}
}

}
.px-video-controls button {
margin: 0 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

  


<body class="fadeIn">

<!-- TODA PROGRAMAÇÃO DEVE SER FEITA DENTRO DA DIV firstBlur!!!-->

<div class="firstBlur">

<div class="navbar-container">

    <ul>
        <li class="nav-link active-link">
            <a href="#">Página inicial
            </a>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Vídeos</a>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Quem somos?</a>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" href="#">Entrar</a>
            <div class="underline">
                
            </div>

        </li>

   
    </ul>

        <div id="search">
<i class="fas fa-search" id="search-icon"></i>
<form>
<input type="text" id="search-input" name="search" autocomplete="off">
</form>
</div>
</div>









<div class="container-fluid" id="hero">
<!-- you can also add something like style="min-height: 70vh;" to the div above -->
<div class="container">


<div class="px-video-container" id="myvid">
<div class="px-video-img-captions-container">

<div class="px-video-wrapper">
  <video poster="images/Logotipo.jpg" class="px-video" controls>
        <!-- video files -->
        <source src="videoteste.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        

        <!-- text track file -->
        

        <!-- fallback for browsers that don't support the video element -->
        <div>
            
                <img src="images/Logotipo.jpg" class="logo2" alt="download video" />
            
        </div>
    </video>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end container for captions and video -->
<div class="px-video-controls"></div>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h2 class ="ti">Bem vindo ao site do <h2 class=
        "t1" style="color:#008080">Projeto AVAL!</h2></h2>
        <p>
            <h5 class="t1">Assista esse vídeo que explica nosso projeto:</h5>
        </p> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid" id="hero2">
<div class="row2">
    <div class="col">
      <strong><h2 class="t2" style="color:black">Funcionalidades do site</h2></strong>>

    
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid" id="hero3">
<div class="row2">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="images/iconv.png" class="iconv"/>
        <img src="images/iconc.png" class="iconc"/>
        <img src="images/iconi.png" class="iconi"/>
    
    </div>
</div>
</div>




<div class="container-fluid" id="hero4">
<div class="col-sm-8"></div>
<div class="row3">      
 <div class="col">             
 </div>           
</div>
</div>








<div class="container-fluid" id="hero5">
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="row3">      
 <div class="col">             
 </div>           
</div>
</div>







</div>














<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color:black">Faça o login!</h5>


            </div>



            <div class="modal-body">


                <!-- Início do formulário -->

                <form class="log">
                    <div class="imgcontainer">

                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src="logotipo.png" alt="Avatar" class="logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="uname"><b>Nome</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="uname" required>

                        <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha" name="psw" required>

                        <button type="submit" class="shadow-pop-tr" style="background-color:#008080">Entrar</button>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Lembrar de mim
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container1" style="background-color:#008080; height: 60px;">

                        <span class="psw" style="margin-top:0px">Esqueceu a<a href="#"> senha?</a></span>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- Fim do formulário -->







<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/strings.js"></script>
<script src="js/px-video.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
  (function() {
    //Show Modal
    $('#exampleModalLong').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $('.firstBlur').addClass('modalBlur');
    })
    //Remove modal
    $('#exampleModalLong').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $('.firstBlur').removeClass('modalBlur');
    })
})();


$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
    $('.active-link').removeClass('active-link');
    $(this).addClass('active-link');
});
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('#search');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input');
let active = false;

body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
if(e.target.id === 'search' || e.target.id === 'search-input' || e.target.id === 'search-icon') {
if(!active) {
searchBtn.classList.add('active');
searchInput.classList.add('active');
active = true;
}
} else {
searchBtn.classList.remove('active');
searchInput.classList.remove('active');
searchInput.value = '';
active = false;
}
});

new InitPxVideo({
videoId: "myvid",
captionsOnDefault: true,
seekInterval: 20,
videoTitle: "PayPal Austin promo",
debug: true
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```